# Аппроксимация движения пальца в кривые Безье

Tags: android, алгоритм

Существуют ли готовые решения для  Android?
Если нет, как лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, вы можете отследить точки начала и конца, max и min отклонения и использовать преобразования bezier. В классе Path, есть Квадратичные и Кубические преобразования кривых [cubicTo](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#cubicTo(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float)) и [quadTo](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#quadTo(float,%20float,%20float,%20float))

Вот простой пример для теста с методом quadTo:

```
public class DrawBezierLine extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(new DrawView(this));
}

class DrawView extends View {
    Paint p;
    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        p.setStrokeWidth(5);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawPath(makeBezierLine(50, 50, 200, 300), p);

    }
}
private Path makeBezierLine(float x1, float y1, float x3, float y3) {
    final Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(x1, y1);
    final float x2 = 0;
    final float y2 = 200;
    path.quadTo(x2,y2, x3,y3);
    return path;
    }
}
```

где x1,y1 -начальная точка. x3,y3 - конечная точка,  x2,y2 - точка отклонения.

Но для вашего примера, больше подойдет кубическое преобразование, очень часто используется в рисовалках.

*Добавлю:*  Интерполяторы используют аналогию сложных кривых Безье и могут быть использованы, для решения многих задач. Также никто вам не мешает создать свой алгоритм преобразования, используя свои данные, что может быть актуальней и возможно проще.

Comment: Где можно почитать про кубическое преобразование?

Comment: И задача то не отобразить кривые, а преобразовать массив точек в эти кривые